# on click function in button executing multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, html

Inside while loop executing whole user details, when I click on the button the id of user is passing to function which is outside while loop. And the problem is  when I click on button the value should be passed every 10 or 5 seconds, but in below code when I click the first time it's executing perfectly, but when I click on second or third time, value its executing first, second, third and so on.., if I did any mistake correct me or else any logic??

```
<?php
include("database/connect.php");

$q = mysqli_query($con, "select * from tbl_user");
while ($f = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) { ?>
    <input type="button" name="ch" value="<?= $f['id'] ?>" onclick="fcc(<?= $f['id']?>)"/><br>
<?php } ?>

<script>
function fcc(cc) {
   setInterval(function() {
       alert(cc);
   }, 3000);

}
</script>
```

Comment: 3000 is 3 seconds?

Comment: `setInterval` executes that code every 3 seconds to infinity for first time, second time and n time you click.

Comment: Each time you click you start another repeated alert, but you don't stop the old one.

Comment: ya why you used `setInterval` here

Comment: @Barmar how to stop old one can you please help

Comment: what is your actual purpose?

Comment: @AdeshKumar using ajax i am passing values to another page to refresh chat history of that person in same page div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the interval timer to a global variable, and stop the old timer when you start a new one.

```
var timer;
function fcc(cc) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        alert(cc);
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped lot:)

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the Interval before starting a new one

ES6:

```js
{
  let interval;
  function fcc(cc) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(fcc.callback.bind({}, [cc]), 1000);
  }
  window.fcc = fcc;
}

fcc.callback = function myAlert(m) {
  console.log(m)
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="ch" value="a" onclick="fcc('a')" /><br>
<input type="button" name="ch" value="b" onclick="fcc('b')" /><br>
<input type="button" name="ch" value="c" onclick="fcc('c')" /><br>
```

Or with ES5

```js
function _fcc() {
  var interval;
  
  return function (m) {
    clearInterval(interval)
    interval = setInterval(fcc.callback.bind({}, [m]), 1000);
  }
}
fcc = _fcc();

fcc.callback = function myAlert(m) {
  console.log(m)
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="ch" value="a" onclick="fcc('a')" /><br>
<input type="button" name="ch" value="b" onclick="fcc('b')" /><br>
<input type="button" name="ch" value="c" onclick="fcc('c')" /><br>
```